# How to optimize join and sub-query in pgSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've 2 tables in PostgreSQL, Schema ==> **sts**

1. `product_price_log` contains columns `product_name` (character varying), K (numeric), `sale_date` (date)
2. `product_transaction` contains columns `product_name` (character varying), `price` (numeric), `sale_date` (date)

I want to get json data for `sale_date = '2018-01-15' and '2018-01-01'`.

Product **price** should be from `product_price_log` table and sale data from `product_transaction` table for summarized report.

this my query:

```
(SELECT 
    json_agg(j.*)
from(
    select 
        a.sale_date, a.product_name, sum(a.quantity) as quantity, sum( a.quantity * b.price) as total_sale
    from(
        select
            sale_date, product_name, quantity
        from 
            sts.product_transaction p
        where 
        sale_date = '2018-01-15' or sale_date = '2018-01-01' and quantity > 0
    )a
    inner join (

        select * from(
          select product_name, price, sale_date from sts.product_price_log where sale_date <= '2018-01-15' order by sale_date desc limit 1
            union all
          select product_name, price, sale_date from sts.product_price_log where sale_date <= '2018-01-01' order by sale_date desc limit 1
        )a order by sale_date

    )r on (a.product_name = r.product_name and a.sale_date = r.sale_date)
    group by 
        sale_date,
        product_name
)j)
;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=230444.51..230444.52 rows=1 width=28)
  ->  Subquery Scan on j  (cost=230290.98..230444.50 rows=1 width=28)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=230290.98..230444.49 rows=1 width=20)
```

How to I reduce time cost or optimize this query?

Comment: That's not the full query plan, post the whole thing please. Since joining on the `r` subquery would seem quite fast, my guess is the `a` query is slow - maybe it returns a huge amount of records, or it searches through a table with a lot of records without using indexes? But I'd need to see the actual query plan to determine that.

Comment: Indexes are present in all where Claus column.  Yes, 'a' query returns huge row(s). sts.product_transaction contains 10m row(s) +.  Filter: (((sale_date = '2018-01-15'::date) OR (sale_date = '2018-01-01'::date)) AND (quantity  > '0'::numeric)). 
->  Seq Scan on product_price_log product_price_log_1  (cost=0.00..17756.29 rows=638411 width=19)
Filter: (sale_date <= '2018-03-15'::date)
May I've to use any another technique to optimize this query?